# PyCharm unresolved reference when importing from the same folder

Tags: python, pycharm

When I just created a new project I had two py files - main.py and functions.py - in the project folder "my project". In **main.py** I imported **functions.py** and it worked fine. But then I created some folders in "my project" folder and put **main.py** and **functions.py** in one of them. They are still in the same folder, but in **main.py** it says that **functions.py** is an unresolved reference.

P.S. Using PyCharm on macos

Comment: can you post the structure of the folders and files in those folders? also, the code where you import functions.py might be useful to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you should make a package in your directory tree and PyCharm will pick it up easily.

```
project_root
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── functions.py
```

Open `project_root` in PyCharm and these imports should work correctly:

```
from my_project import functions
```

or

```
import my_project.functions
# you can also do 'import my_project.functions as functions'

my_project.functions.do_something('argument')
```